# javascript object equality / identity - comparison

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, comparison, polling

I've got this code

```
    update_questions: function() {
        alert("UPDATING!!");
    },
    poll: function() {
        var self = this;

        $.post(
            self.o.site_root+'home/ajax_poll',
            function(questions) {
                if (questions != self.o.questions) {
                    self.o.questions = questions;
                    self.update_questions();
                }
                self.o.pending = false;
            },
            'json'
        );
    },
```

Can anyone explain to me why the `update_questions` function is being called every time?  I thought, especially after `self.o.questions = questions;` that the returning `questions` and `self.o.questions` would have to be equal if not identical.

The data is not changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through the properties and compare them, recursively comparing any properties of whom their value is another object.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting it from a post request and while the objects properties may be equal, they're two differnet objects in memory and will not be equal. You need to compare the actual values the objects has within, and not the objects themselves.

Here's a simple demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/jwhwt/